# How to set a value to variable from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create this function, this return the final score of a student in a subject, this student can take the test multiple times

```
create function finalResult(@stC varchar(10), @sj varchar(10))
returns float
as begin
    declare @result float
    set @result = (select sum(score)/count(studentCode) 
                   from Results 
                   where @stC = studentCode and @sj = subject)
    return @result
end
```

The problem here is it says "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client" when I remove the () wrapping the select. Idk how this thing works can anyone explain

Comment: BTW, you'll get an error due to divide-by-zero when `count(studentCode) == 0`

Comment: Also, why are you doing `count(studentCode)` instead of `count(*)` ?

Comment: 1. `select @result = ....` 2. no need for a variable you can just `return( select... ) `3. Why are you using `float`? 4. consider using a table-valued function not a scalar function.

Answer (score 1):

you can thin it down a bit.   I am also assuming `SCORE` is NOT an int

**Example**

```
create function finalResult(@stC varchar(10), @sj varchar(10))
returns float   --<< consider using a decimal()
as 
begin
   return (
            select sum(score)/nullif(count(*) ,0)   -- added a divide by zero error trap
              from Results 
              where @stC = studentCode 
                and @sj  = subject
          )
end
```